# Pagina en blanco a la hora de imprimir una sentencia Mysql usando Laravel

Tags: html, mysql, laravel

Tengo esta sentencia mysql

```
public function mayores(Request $req){$taquito=DB::select('select * from clientes where edad = ?', [18]);view('Layouts.mayores',compact('taquito'));}
```

para sacar todos mis clientes con edad mayor a 18 años la cual se encuentra dentro de mi controlador y utilizo esta ruta para entrar a la página `Route::get('/mayores','Pincipalcontroller@mayores');`

siendo "Principalcontroller" mi controlador donde tengo todas las sentencias y todo llega a esta vista

[image: Vista de mayores de edad]

pero siempre mi resultado termina siendo una página totalmente en blanco ni siquiera se ve lo que es el menú ligado a la vista ni las columnas de la tabla aún sin llenar alguna solucion? tengo impresiones para ver todos los clientes la cual funciona bien pero al intentar filtrarlos me sale todo mal y no encuentro la solucion

[image: Ejemplo de la página en blanco]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que pude apreciar tu problema está en varios lugares
1 en tu fichero de rutas no especificas bien que controladora va a ser la encargada de responder a tu solicitud en la ruta **/mayores**
Tu controladora se llama PrincipalController y le pasas al Route::get **PincipalController** (Tal vez sea error al copiar tu texto para aca, porque de lo contrario te hubiera lanzado alguna excepción)

2 El más importante, en tu función de la Controladora debes devolver la vista que vas a renderizar, y hasta donde puede ver solo ejecutas la función view

Debe ser:

```
public function mayores(Request $req){
    $taquito=DB::select('select * from clientes where edad = ?', [18]);
    /*Antes tenias view('Layouts.mayores',compact('taquito')); te faltaba el return*/
    return view('Layouts.mayores',compact('taquito'));
}
```

Comment: Dios no puedo creer que malgaste tiempo de la gente por un tonto return que no pude ver perdón!!!!

Comment: Jajjaa eso pasa amigo. No problem